# LINQ query to get data from two databases

Tags: database, linq, entity-framework

I have two databases:

1. `MasterDB`
2. `ChildDB`

In `MasterDB` I have the following tables:

- `Customer_Table`
- `Tenant_Table`
- `Customer-Tenant_Table`

In `Customer_Table` I have:

- `CustomerId`
- `CustomerName`

In `Tenant_Table` I have:

- `TenantId`
- `TenantName`

In `Customer-Tenant_Table`:

- `Customer-Tenant_Id`
- `CustomerId`
- `TenantID`

And now in `ChildDB` I have a table `FacilityGroup_Table`
which has:

- `TenantID`
- `FacilityGroupId`
- etc.…

What I'm trying to do here is the following.  In my view, I have a dropdown that is being populated from the `Customer_Table` from the `MasterDB`.  On the basis of that `CustomerName`, the corresponding `CustomerID` is being captured.  Now, the problem is that I am clueless how to use that `CustomerId` to get the corresponding `TenantId` and save the same `TenantId` inside the `FacilityGroup_Table` inside my `ChildDB`.  I'm new to LINQ, so I could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Write a View in the master DB, to join the table from different DB's, that would return the result you want, and then query that View.

Comment: Let me know if You need additional help